# Python: O ^ não está transformando a character class do meu regex em negativa

Tags: python, regex

Estou aprendendo REGEXes pelo Automate the Boring Stuff w/ Python. Em um dos títulos do capítulo 7, o livro ensina sobre caractere classes. Até aí tranquilo. Criei character classes para vogais (`re.compile(r'[aeiouAEIOU]')`), para letras e dígitos em intervalos (`(r'a-zA-Z0-9')`)... Tudo tranquilo.

Quando comecei a aprender sobre negative character classes, ou seja, definir uma character class e fazer com que sejam detectadas, em um texto, por exemplo, as strings que NÃO possuírem a combinação de caracteres que eu definir pela character class, comecei a encontrar dificuldades.

Uma character class negativa se declara assim: `re.compile(r'[ˆaeiouAEIOU]')`, com o chapeuzinho na frente. Mas isso não está tornando a character class negativa: na verdade, está detectando vogais E o chapeuzinho, se tiver chapeuzinho na frase.

Veja:

```
#Tentando (e conseguindo) detectar só VOGAIS...
>>> consonantRegex = re.compile(r'[aeiouAEIOU]')
>>> consonantRegex.findall('Robocop eats baby food. BABY FOOD')
['o', 'o', 'o', 'e', 'a', 'a', 'o', 'o', 'A', 'O', 'O']

#Tentando detectar só CONSOANTES... (Perceba o chapeuzinho)
>>> consonantRegex = re.compile(r'[ˆaeiouAEIOU]')
>>> consonantRegex.findall('Robocop eats baby food. BABY FOOD')
['o', 'o', 'o', 'e', 'a', 'a', 'o', 'o', 'A', 'O', 'O']

#Colocando um chapeuzinho na frase -> Chapeuzinho detectado
>>> consonantRegex.findall('Robocop eats baby food. ˆBABY FOOD.')
['o', 'o', 'o', 'e', 'a', 'a', 'o', 'o', 'ˆ', 'A', 'O', 'O']
```

Dados:

1. Estou usando o *interactive shell* do THONNY, mas também já testei no próprio IDLE, mesmo erro.
2. Uso Mac. Sabemos que o Mac tem aquele feature chato que atrapalha muito na programação: a questão dos acentos. Quando coloco aspas, por exemplo, ele fica esperando uma vogal pra ver se dá pra acentuar. Tipo *ä*. Aí tem que colocar aspas, digitar uma consoante, tipo *s*, aí fica *"s* normal, e depois apagar o *s* pra digitar a vogal desejada anteriormente. (Se alguém souber como desativa isso, mas de forma que ainda dê pra usar acentos, também agradeço MUITO).

Answer (score 8):

Seu 2º dado responde sua própria pergunta.

Realmente o MacOS trabalha com modificadores, que na verdade, utiliza outros tipos de caracteres para acentuação, por exemplo:

(MacOS) <kbd>ˆ</kbd> `(U+02C6) MODIFIER LETTER CIRCUMFLEX ACCENT`. Quando o caractere do acento é:

(Outros)  <kbd>^</kbd> `(U+005E) CIRCUMFLEX ACCENT`.

Para arrumar esse problema em seu teclado, siga [estas](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/234357)<sup><sup>[veja edição]</sup></sup> instruções.
Se quiser testar o regex antes de realizar tais alterações, tente usar o código a seguir:

```
consonantRegex = re.compile(r'[^aeiouAEIOU]')
```

---

### Edição (28/09/2017):

Para ajudar outras pessoas do Stack a procurarem pela pergunta, aqui está a tradução das instruções acima:

**(pt-BR):** Você deverá ir às configurações do teclado (*Keyboard Preferences*), e adicionar um novo teclado.

Ao invés de utilizar o 
[*USA International keyboard* <sup>[1]</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tg9PT.png) você deverá usar o 
[*USA Keyboard* <sup>[2]</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vV4Ke.png).

Então de

[image: Estadounidense internacional - PC]

Use como alternativa

[image: Estadounidense]

1. Quando você for adicionar um novo teclado, selecione Inglês (ou *English*, se quiser continuar com o teclado americado do Mac).
2. No final da lista você verá os dois teclados. Use a opção que **não** seja `internacional`.

[image: Example]

---

**[ ! ]** Uma outra opção é ao colocar o `ˆ`, antes de clicar qualquer outra tecla, pressione a tecla de espaço.

Comment: Percebi a algo assim quando vi o circunflexo pequeno.